# Stop Eclipse deleting resource files when it builds

Tags: eclipse

I have some data resources that I would like eclipse to not copy every time it builds. I put them as part of the build path so they get copied, but I don't want that to happen every time as it's time consuming.

Any idea on a better strategy? 
I don't even want them to be deleted when clean is invoked. In Visual Studio one can mark a resource file as "copy once" is there such a thing in Eclipse.

Thank You

Comment: Why not just use incremental build?

Comment: I usually do, but sometimes IvyIde gets messed up and I need to clean, I would like eclipse not to delete those resources when it cleans

Answer (score 1):

Having eclipse not copy some file that you have modified even after a clean will be a nightmare: you'll have to remember to copy it manually each time it's modified.

And Eclipse only copies files which have been modified when building incrementally.

If it's so slow, it probably means you have too many such files, and they should perhaps be put in a jar in the build path.

Answer (score 1):

As you ask for a strategy, then ...
Eclipse is not a build tool, it's IDE. So you better not try to setup some build logic based on it. Use eclipse for coding and for performing specific tasks during build use build tools like maven or ant.